# How can I disable dragging in one direction with a flickity wrapAround carousel?

Tags: flickity

I have a simple 30 item Flickity carousel with wrapAround set to true. Is there away to disable dragging from right to left but leave left to right dragging working?

I can turn it on/off like so:

$carousel.flickity('unbindDrag');

But I don't want it disabled in both directions